# Share button on my web application

Tags: javascript, html, facebook

I want to add a button to share a picture. This is my code in tag body:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="my_image"></div>
```

Don't work. When i run my page.html it show an error:

GET file://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

However I WANT TO SHARE WITHOUT ID_APP!

Comment: To avoid people's private photo's being yanked, you need to have a Facebook Application that request such permissions.  Otherwise it wouldn't be secure.

Comment: Test it on a real webserver. Or change //connect to https://connect

Answer (score 0):

Since you're testing this locally using a file path, "file:" is prepended onto the URL for the facebook script, hence the "file://connect.facebook.net". If you change the url to use "http:" or "https:" in the script, it should work as desired.

Comment: I change the url to "http//connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0" and i have this error: Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. In this way, I need to register my app to receive an id but i don't want

Comment: Don't forget the colon; it should be `http://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0`

Comment: i have this error: Invalid App Id: Must be a number or numeric string representing the application id. In this way, I need to register my app to receive an id but i don't want

Comment: So you need to modify the URL to contain your app id. Something like
`http://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.0&appId=1234567891234567`

Comment: yes but i don't want register my web app for an id.

Comment: It's not possible to use that particular sharer without an app id, so you'd have to look into another solution